# Android - Changing Text For TextViews For a Dynamically Added Layout

Tags: android, textview, android-button, android-cardview

I have a `CardView` which contains a `RelativeLayout` with a few **TextView's** and a button. I have succeeded in adding them dynamically to a layout. But I want to change the text of these **TextView's** programmatically (different text for different cards) and I have no idea how to do so. How do I achieve this?

> The CardView XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/CardView_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardElevation="20dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="45dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1.25dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Assignments"
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Homework"
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Exams"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="TASKS"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Personal Notes"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:id="@+id/textView13"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView11" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:id="@+id/textView14"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView13" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/textView15"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView14" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/textView16"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/note_button"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView15"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="38dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SCHEDULE"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_weight="0.09"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Class No: "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/t_dur"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Subject"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/t_sub"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="Room No: "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/t_roomno"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Code to add layout(b, c, d are TextViews):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.badd:
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cardtest);

            LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lladd);
            View v1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card, ll2, false);

            try{

                b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_dur);
                c = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_sub);
                d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t_roomno);

                if (i > 1) {
                    ll2.addView(v1);
                    Log.v("DEBUG: ", "Inside IF");

                    b.setId(View.generateViewId());
                    c.setId(View.generateViewId());
                    d.setId(View.generateViewId());

                    b.setText("Class No: " + i);
                    c.setText("Subject: " + i);
                    d.setText("Room No: " + i);
                }else{
                    Log.v("DEBUG: ", "Inside ELSE");
                    CardView cv = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.CardView_1);
                    cv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    b.setText("Class No: " + i);
                    c.setText("Subject: " + i);
                    d.setText("Room No: " + i);
                }
                i++;
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.v("DEBUG: ", e.toString());
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code please...

Answer (score 0):

You can create `ArrayList` of **Textview's** so you can access that whenever you want.

```
arrList.add(b);
```

like this and access that and set Text to it when you want.

Comment: But that's only for 1 card. What if I want to change texts on multiple cards?

Comment: You can use Expandable `ListView` then.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: see this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: In expandable list view you can add item in list item and render in list